# JavaScript Array how to choose content

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to use JavaScript array inside html. I want to use the content of `<p id="byteState_0">`. I get inside this a number 0-3 and depends on the number I get inside my `<p id="byteState_0">` I would like to get the string inside `<p id="differentStates">`. But I dont know how to select the content of `<p id="byteState_0">`

```js
var states = ["State 0", "State 1", "State 2", "State 3"];
document.getElementById("differentStates").innerHTML = states[document.getElementById("byteState_0")];
```

```html
<p id="differentStates"></p>
<p id="byteState_0">2</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML)

```
document.getElementById("byteState_0").innerHTML
```

```js
var states = ["State 0", "State 1", "State 2", "State 3"];
document.getElementById("differentStates").innerHTML = states[document.getElementById("byteState_0").innerHTML];
```

```html
<p id="differentStates"></p>
<p id="byteState_0">2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there

The way you can get the content of an element is the same than setting it, using `element.innerHTML`

```js
const states = ["State 0", "State 1", "State 2", "State 3"];
// Check this --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------v--------v
document.getElementById("differentStates").innerHTML = states[document.getElementById("byteState_0").innerHTML];
```

```html
<p id="differentStates"></p>  
<p id="byteState_0">2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("differentStates").innerHTML=states[document.getElementById("byteState_0").textContent];